# Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904 ... System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent, jobs, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that is executed every 30 seconds by a SQL Agent Job. Every few days, an execution will fail with this message in the Job History:

> Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904.
>   Server: MyServer, Package path:
>   \SSISDB\Packages\MyProject\MyPackage.dtsx, Environment reference Id:
>   1.  Description: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "start_execution_internal":
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid 
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:      at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.CreateCallerToken(IntPtr&
>   callerToken, IntPtr& lpEnvironmentInfo)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.StartExecutionInternal(SqlInt64
>   projectId, SqlInt64 executionId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt16
>   use32BitRuntime)  .  Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going wrong and what I can do to prevent the error?

Comment: `internal.start_execution_internal` is a CLR method in the SSISDB that ships from MS. Best I can think of is to check system health XE and SQL error log to see if you can correlate system activity to the exceptions. The other semi-obvious thing is to ensure you're on current patch level. After that, it might warrant a call to CSS

Comment: @billinkc: Thanks. The instance is 2012 SP2, so it could use an update. From the logs, it also looks like it could use a bit more RAM: "AppDomain 39394 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].41572) is marked for unload due to memory pressure." I'll get it the TLC it needs.